# Unable to connect my computer from LAN (http, smb)

Tags: 10.04, networking

I installed ubuntu 10.04, Apache, PHP, mysql, smb. Everything work fine in locally in my IP. When i trying to access my computer from LAN (other computer), it shows unable to connect. when i ping my IP from remote computer, its pinging OK. I can access internet, and all other systems (http, smb). But the problem is no one can't access my computer remotely in my LAN network.

My ip is 192.168.85.105 and i want access(Appaceh,SMB) from 192.168.85.10.

Is there any proxy firewall settings?

When i re-starting the system the same problem still exist.The system correctly ping from remote host.I have executed the above commands.Initially i run the command "sudo iptables -F" its okey in first time. now its not working, Please assist me ...

[OUTPUT OF iptables --list is given]**

```
    ashok@ashok-desktop:~$ sudo iptables --list
    [sudo] password for ashok: 
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  resolver1.opendns.com  anywhere            tcp flags:!FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN 
    ACCEPT     udp  --  resolver1.opendns.com  anywhere            
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 10/sec burst 5 
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             255.255.255.255     
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             192.168.85.255      
    DROP       all  --  base-address.mcast.net/8  anywhere            
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             base-address.mcast.net/8 
    DROP       all  --  255.255.255.255      anywhere            
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             0.0.0.0             
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID 
    LSI        all  -f  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 10/min burst 5 
    INBOUND    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    LOG_FILTER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `Unknown Input' 

    Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 10/sec burst 5 
    LOG_FILTER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `Unknown Forward' 

    Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.85.105       resolver1.opendns.com tcp dpt:domain 
    ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.85.105       resolver1.opendns.com udp dpt:domain 
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    DROP       all  --  base-address.mcast.net/8  anywhere            
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             base-address.mcast.net/8 
    DROP       all  --  255.255.255.255      anywhere            
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             0.0.0.0             
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state INVALID 
    OUTBOUND   all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    LOG_FILTER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            LOG level info prefix `Unknown Output' 

    Chain INBOUND (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    LSI        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

    Chain LOG_FILTER (5 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:hkp 
    DROP       udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:hkp 

    Chain LSI (2 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    LOG_FILTER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level info prefix `Inbound ' 
    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN 
    LOG        tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/RST limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level info prefix `Inbound ' 
    DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/RST 
    LOG        icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level info prefix `Inbound ' 
    DROP       icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/sec burst 5 LOG level info prefix `Inbound ' 
    DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

    Chain LSO (0 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    LOG_FILTER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
    LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/sec burst 5 LOG level info prefix `Outbound ' 
    REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

    Chain OUTBOUND (1 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Please give me the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you change your ip-table settings ? Try to reset iptables

```
sudo iptables -F
```

or

```
sudo iptables-restore
```

[logout require] If it does not work then try to disable net-filter

```
sudo ufw --disable
```

Comment: Thanks your valuable time...We are searched long time....

Comment: When i re-starting the system the same problem still exist.The system correctly  ping from remote  host.I have executed the above commands.Initially i run the command "sudo iptables -F" its okey in first time. now its not working. I tried all command you mentioned above, Please assist me  ...

Comment: please paste the output of this command: sudo iptables --list

Comment: plz check the updated question with output of  sudo iptables --list